# COUNTIF relative reference

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Should just be an easy solution, but I need your help.

I have a number of columns of information and I want to summarise them. I'll draw an example below:

```
row    a             b             c             d            e
1      Question no.  subject area  Answer no.    STUDENT 1    STUDENT 2
2      1             maths         A             A            A
3      2             maths         D             D            B
4      3             science       C             A            C
5      4             maths         A             A            A
```

What is the best formula to use to 'count' 1 for each response that each student gets right. I want to create a countif formula (maybe this isn't the best one) to work out if their score in column D or E, equals the value in column C, and be able to split this up for subject matter.

```
=COUNTIFS( b2:b5, "maths"   ,    d2:d5 , c2:c5=ds:d5  )
```

The first bit of the formula works (identifying how many 'maths' questions.

My problem is that I can't get (or work out) how to count=1 when each student score equals the relative value in column C.

Any thoughts?

Comment: `=SUMPRODUCT((B2:B5="maths")*(C2:C5=D2:D5))`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't that would be possible using countIf. A non VBA solution that I would consider is adding the new columns G and H. 
Put the following formula in G3 and drag to the rest of the range in columns G and H:

```
=IF(E3=$D3, 1, 0)
```

Then sum the "1"s in G7 and H7:

```
=SUM(G3:G6)
```

Result:

[image]